# Why is λ called "LAMDA" instead of "LAMBDA" in Unicode

Tags: unicode

Looking at the *Unicode Character Database*, I noticed that the λ character, which is usually called "lambda" in English, is in fact spelled "lamda" (or `GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMDA`, to be exact).

Even though I understand that the transliteration of λ in Modern Greek is "lamda", what were the official reasons for using the less common name, especially for other characters, like `MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL LAMDA`, which do not have the other version of the character name at all?

Comment: See [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda#Character_encodings).

Comment: Wikipedia (thank you @AFH) links to [this](https://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2010-m06/0063.html). `All three were spelled "LAMBDA" in Unicode 1.0. 
039B/03BB were changed to "LAMDA" as part of the synchronization 
with 10646-1 in 1993. And those changes were motivated by 
the pre-existing names in ISO 8859-7, as I mentioned before, 
as well as by preferences expressed by the Greek National Body.` It doesn't look opinion-based. I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: @ThomasDickey - Yes, it does, in the first sentence of the section.